# Help understanding the output from Apache Commons Math's Discrete Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation

I'm using a discrete Fourier transform to translate a finite set of samples to the frequency domain. I'm trying to start with a very simple set, but am still getting confused.
I'm starting with this set of samples:

$$\{   1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0\}$$

I expected to get output indicating that the frequency domain representation of this set was expressed by
1*cos(t)
But instead I get:
Raw output:

$$\{  4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0\}$$

My (possibly flawed) interpretation of the output:

```
Frequency representation=
```

$$  4.0\cos(2\pi/1)+$$
  $$  0.0\cos(2\pi/2)+$$
   $$ 0.0\cos(2\pi/3)+$$
   $$ 0.0\cos(2\pi/4)+$$
   $$ 4.0\cos(2\pi/5)+$$
   $$ 0.0\cos(2\pi/6)+$$
   $$ 0.0\cos(2\pi/7)+$$
   $$ 0.0\cos(2\pi/8)$$

Why are the coefficients $4$?

Why, when my source data has a very simple repeating pattern, do I have more than one entry in the frequency domain representation?

If my output interpretation of correct, how should I interpret the resulting function? Here's a [graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4cos%282pix%29%20%2B%204cos%282pix%2F5%29).

I'm using an Apache math library's implementation of the DFT (Commons math 3-3.3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input is not just cosine. Cosine function has zero mean. Your function has mean $1/2$. It is  accurately represented by 
$$
\frac12 + \frac12 \cos 4 t,\quad t=0,\pi/4,\pi/2,3\pi/4,\dots,7\pi/4
$$
This means: coefficient $1/2$ of frequency $0$, coefficient $1/2$ of frequency $4$.

The output lists frequencies beginning with $0$. Also, the normalization of the transform in this routine happens to be such that instead of the Fourier coefficients themselves you get $N$ times them, where $N$ is the length of your vector. Dividing by $8$ gives the vector of coefficients.

Generally, the  Fourier transform involves complex exponential functions $e^{ikt}=\cos kt+i\sin kt$. You don't see the sines here because the input data is "even".

The implementation you are using gives the same result as [Matlab's fft command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html), so I refer there for the complete list of formulas for the direct and inverse transform implemented by this function.

---

> suppose I had an input dataset that gave me both real and imaginary values in my coefficient vector. How can I usefully factor the imaginary values into a result? What do the imaginary values effectively 'mean'?

Let's take a more generic example (I rounded Matlab output below) :

```
fft([1 0 2 3 0 4 -1 0])  = [9, -4-2i, -i, 6+4i, -5, 6-4i, i, -4+3i]
```

The easiest way to see how the output $X$ represents the input $x$ is to look up the inverse command (`ifft` in Matlab), because this is the thing that recovers original vector. Its formula is

$$x(j) =  \frac1N \sum_{k=1}^8 X(k) e^{-2\pi i(j-1)(k-1)/N} \tag{1}$$

(which is unfortunately mistyped on the Matlab page). Although both $X$ and the complex exponentials involve complex numbers, the result of summation will be real if your input $x$ is real. Therefore, we can simplify the matter by keeping only the real part of (1):

$$x(j) =  \frac1N \sum_{k=1}^8 (\operatorname{Re}X(k))\cos( 2\pi i(j-1)(k-1)/N) 
\\+ \frac1N \sum_{k=1}^8 (\operatorname{Im}X(k))\sin( 2\pi i(j-1)(k-1)/N) 
 \tag{2}$$

With specific numbers: 
$$x(j) =  \frac18 (9-4\cos (2\pi (j-1)/8)+6\cos (2\pi (j-1)(4-1)/8) - 5\cos (2\pi (j-1)(5-1)/8) + \dots)
 + \frac18 ( -2 \sin(2\pi (j-1)/8)-\sin(2\pi (j-1)(3-1)/8) +4\sin(2\pi (j-1)(4-1)/8)   \dots)
$$ 
This should recover the input `[1 0 2 3 0 4 -1 0]` for $j=1,\dots,8$, but I was too lazy to type in all the terms. The formulas are easier to write if the arrays use $0$-based indexed, but Matlab has $1$-based indices.

Comment: suppose I had an input dataset that gave me both real and imaginary values in my coefficient vector. How can I usefully factor the imaginary values into a result? What do the imaginary values effectively 'mean'?

Comment: I added an explanation.